# What is the problem with parameters in the constructor of a Class in Java?

Tags: java, constructor, final

In this code if I keep `int i` in the parameterized constructor, it throws an error. If anything other than `int i` is working fine.

Example: `int j` works fine. What is the reason for this error, please enlighten my knowledge.

```
//this program throws an error
class X
{ 
    final int i;
    X()
    {
        i = 0;
    }
    X(int i)//need to keep other than i
    {
        i = 20;
    }
}

//this program works fine
class X
{ 
    final int i;
    X()
    {
        i = 0;
    }   
    X(int j)
    {
        i = 20;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need `this.i = 20;`

Comment: I think you already have the correct answer, but for future reference it would be better to say _what_ error you're seeing.

Answer (score 6):

In

```
X(int i)
{
    i = 20;
}
```

The local variable `i` (the argument of the constructor) hides the instance variable `i`. Therefore `i = 20;` modifies the local variable, not the `final` instance variable of the same name, which remains uninitialized.

You can avoid this issue with:

```
X(int i)
{
    this.i = 20;
}
```

or

```
X(int i)
{
    this.i = i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class X
{ 
    final int i;
    X()
    {
        i = 0;
    }
```

What you are saying above is basically that your `i` is equal to 0 if no parameters are given. It is the same as saying `i=0`or `this.i=0`. Same thing as there is only one `i`, so `this`is not really needed.

On the other side, below, there are 2 instances of `i`, so you need to make sure Java knows which one is which one. In this case, imagine you wanted to equal the `i`of `X`, to the `i`passed as a parameter: 
`this.i=i;`is what you would be looking for. "My `i` of the class should be the `i` passed as a parameter.

So in this case, if your constructor receives an int, it should give YOUR `i`the value `20`. If your parameter was `j`, as `j`is not defined in your class, it takes the `i`as the `i`of your class. But having 2 `i`, you should make sure which one is which one!

```
 X(int i)//need to keep other than i
    {
//the i of my class should be 20. remember! this.i=i if you want the i of your class to be equal to the parameter passed i
            this.i = 20;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code above you're never initializing the variable `final int i` which should either be done when declaring this variable or in the constructors of your class, even though you're doing `i = 20;` you're refering to the `int i` which is part of the parameters of that method.

If you wanted to change the value of `final int i` and have a parameter named `i` in your method, you have to call `this.i = 20;` and it will be fixed.